# How to set the default length of float column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have created a table and 1 of the columns in it is float (named ratio),

also have 2x int columns of type INT (KILL and DEATH), ratio column updated automatically by trigger (each time KILL or DEATH is updated the ratio is updated by the trigger),

the size of the float column (ratio) is too big, i mean its length is too long, how i can make define the size of a float column by default?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Well, you should probably use DECIMAL instead of FLOAT, for starters.

Comment: You could use a computed column if you can't spare 32 bits in each row.

Comment: "it's length is too long" - can you clarify what you mean by that?  Do you want to store the data at a fixed precision (say 2 decimal places), or do you just want to display it cleanly after you pull it out?

Comment: hi, by saying the length too long i mean i want only to column to display x.xxx for example, but as Aaron said i should use decimal. Thanks alot Aaron!

Answer (score 1):

The ratio between two columns is something you ought to be calculating on the fly, as you query the tables.  Using a trigger is overkill, IMHO.  You could use a view or a calculated column if you are concerned about repeating your logic (such as avoiding division by zero) over and over.

Formatting of a column (how many decimal places) is an application or report issue, not so much a database issue.  If at some point you decide that you actually want more precision in one of several displays, you'll have to make database changes rather than just app changes.  You also might have a problem if you ever had a ratio of 1 in 1000 or smaller: if you limit yourself to 3 decimal places, your ratio will be calculated as 0, which might cause problems in your logic.